# Flashgot No Longer Compatible With Firefox Quantum (57)...Any Fix?

Tags: firefox, curl, wget

For previous versions of Firefox and Chrome even, life was seamlessly smooth about my cozy style of having Wget and Curl intercept downloads in my browsers with a flashgot extension installed. But all these went south after the new upgrades to the Firefox Quantum and now I can't have wget or curl intercept any of the downloads except the boring built-in download manager from Firefox.
Does anyone have a fix or a working tweak to this lag?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Quantum. Anything up to [Version 54.0.1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/54.0.1/) should be compatible. If you are worried about bug fixes, there are also the [Extended Support Release](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) versions (currently 52.3, I believe).

Comment: I am using elementary os loki and firefox was updated to quantum. There is no point downgrading all in the name of flashgot extension. I think I will wait till a version compatible is released for quantum and above. Thank you @Anaksunaman

Comment: Not a problem. Genuinely hope you don't have to wait too long. I have a few extensions myself I am crossing my fingers will be updated soon as well. =)

Comment: We can only hope.

Answer (score -1):

I have read somewhere that the Flashgot developers are yet to roll out a version compatible for Firefox Quantum and future releases. So, the best fix now is to wait till that is done. Thank y'all.

Answer (score -1):

As stated [here](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23325#p89791), Flashgot should be fixed only after Noscript (by the same [author](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/user/giorgio-maone/)).

I see Noscript is fixed now. Flashgot should follow.